# Bad Questions with Upvotes & Favourites?

Tags: discussion

There's been a couple of occurrences whereby I've viewed a brand new question, which has been formatted badly, with broken English, and sometimes, the question is off-topic.

The weird thing is that these questions already have upvotes or favourites - as mentioned, they're brand new questions (or were at the time). They're almost always from new users, which puzzles me. Is there something dodgy going on, or have I just happened upon a coincidence?

Below are a couple of examples:

[magento catalog price rules disappear sometimes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34363/magento-catalog-price-rules-disappear-sometimes)

[A master web site able to display products in other website which is independent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34373/a-master-web-site-able-to-display-products-in-other-website-which-is-independent/34381#34381)

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange has quite good algorithms against cheating, so I think no need to be scared by such things. If it is too much, SE will do something :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think StackExchange is built with a lot of scraping processes (cron jobs) and indexing systems in order to keep things fast. These processes run every x minutes. I've seen new questions of new users coming in, but not yet appearing on the review screen until after 10 minutes or so. So in the mean time, people can upvote and favorite this new question.

You can also see this in rankings or queries which are indexed or cached on a daily basis. Also when earning a badge, most of the times it doesn't appear right away.